# Excel - Way to calculate paying salaries

Tags: excel, function

I work at a restaurant chain with about 170 employees. Currently we pay most of them by cash, and our administration team counts 'what bank notes' to pay them manually.

So for example if one of our waiters gets paid 2152 Euro, then the function should calculate the following:

```
100 Euro * 21
50 Euro * 1
2 Euro * 1
```

Anything like that in excel?

Comment: ...what have you tried? Wouldn't `=100*21` work for the calculations? Say in cell A1, A2, and A3, you could have `100`, `50`, `2`, respectively then in B1, B2, B3, you could have `21, `1`, `1`.  Then, in C1, just do `=A1*B1` and drag down. Then in C4, you could do `=sum(C1:C3)` to show the total. Then simply format the currency columns (CTRL+1) and choose "Accounting" or "Currency" and choose the EUR symbol.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think he's asking, given a number, calculate which denomination notes, and how many of each, are needed to pay that amount.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - That's what I was also thinking...So, given `2152`, determine the correct mix of Euro notes that they paid with? ...wouldn't that be near impossible? (Without *way*, *way* more constraints on possible combinations anyways)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Basically looking for the easiest way to pay them in each instance.

Comment: @PászliBalázs I think that's more of a mathematics question than Excel. I can see what you're asking for but also how do you define "easiest way"? Least amount of bills I suppose? What have you tried? I would bet heading over to the mathematics stack exchange would get you farther than here..But again this sounds like a relatively tall order for Excel alone. Also, do y'all not have 5, 10, or 20 EUR notes to pay with? What about 1 EUR coins? Etc... Edit: Also you do have a finite amount of bills so paying one emp. with 21 €100 notes leaves 21 fewer to pay the rest with which can cause issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just one way to do it. I chose to use a helper column to keep the formulas simple for you

Here is how it looks:
[image: cash example]

This formula goes in **B3** and you should drag it down. This column shows the remainder due after each note. E.g. 52€ remaining after 2100€ in 100€ notes has been accounted for)

```
=MOD(B2,A3)
```

Then place this formula in **C3** and drag it down

```
=IF(B2<>B3,(B2-B3)/A3,0)
```

That will give you how many of each note to dispense to the worker.

**Note**
This method simply assumes you want to issue the fewest notes. It would be a good idea to have a table which allows you to indicate if you are out of a particular note so that the model uses 2x€50 notes rather than 100€ notes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to use Truncate & Divide to calculate number of notes for each given note.

for example, to get number of 100 note:

> NumberOf100Note = Trunc(givenAmount/100,0)
>
> NumberOf50Note = Trunc((givenAmount - 100 * NumberOf100Note) / 50, 0)

etc. and etc.

and you can build these very easily in excel, isn't it?